# Instantiating an object outside the methods or construcor?

Tags: java, oop

I am getting confused over this:

```
class ClassA {

   ClassB car = new ClassB();

   ClassA(){
   }

   someMethod(){
   }

}


ClassC{

   ClassC(){    
   }

   someMethod(){
        ClassA spaceship = new ClassA();
   }

}
```

- Class B is not instantiated in the Constructor or in the
  methods. And it is not declared as static either. So, when exactly classB is
  instantiated?
- How long does the 'car' instance live for? In other
  words, what happens to the 'car' instance (of Class B) if the
  'spaceship'instance (of ClassA) gets garbage collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, when exactly classB is instantiated?

I think that `ClassB` is initialized when `ClassA` is initialized. More accurate at first is object allocated to memory then are initialized its fields(so your car variable) and then is called constructor.

> How long does the 'car' instance live for?

as long as `ClassA` lives generally. But if you'll explicitly assign your car to `NULL` so is released also if its "parent" lives.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying, but wondering what the benefits could be in instantiating ClassB in the fields declarations and not in the constructor?

Comment: @Crocodile usually this way is used for declaring static or final fields where you know exactly their initial value(s).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
class A {
    B objectB = new B();

    public A() {
        System.out.println("In A Const");
    }
}

class B {

    public B() {
        System.out.println("In B const");
    }
}

class C {

    C() {}
    public void someMethod() {

        A objectA = new A();

        System.out.println("In method C");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C objectC = new C();
        objectC.someMethod();
    }
}
```

o/p: 
In B const
In A Const
In method C

Whenever an object is created first the constructor is called and before implementing the code in the constructor the variables in that particular class are initialized so thats how first the constructor of class B is executed and then that of class A

Thanks